# Visual Basic - Converting a URI to show as a string in a status bar

Tags: vb.net, browser, uri

I'm fooling around in my VB class trying to make a small stand-alone web browser.

Most of the questions I find involve taking a user-input string and converting it to a URI. My problem is that I want to take the current URI data in my Web Browser object and convert it to a string that I can display in the text box.

For example:

- I go to http://stackoverflow.com
- While navigating, I click on a link.
- When I click the link, my navigation bar will display the URL of the page I move to, and it will update as I go to different pages.

Now I'm attempting to do this by setting the textbox to the Browser's URL value everytime the browser navigates. But the textbox cannot accept URI objects, only strings.

Does anyone know how to convert them or a more efficient manner of doing this update?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about how you're implementing your browser, and your question is tagged VBA yet you mention VB in the text. Going to have to add some more detailed info if you really want help.

Comment: Curious as to why my tag edit (exchanging VBA with another VB variant) was rejected while Lunatik (who approved my edit) was able to make the  same change?

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub webBrowser1_Navigated(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigated
    textbox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Url.ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub Navigate(ByVal address As String)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) Then Return
    If address.Equals("about:blank") Then Return
    If Not address.StartsWith("http://") Then
        address = "http://" & address
    End If
    Try
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri(address))
    Catch ex As System.UriFormatException
        Return
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the URI.ToString method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply display the `AbsoluteURI` from the object in the textbox?